# Add comma separator to seaborn heatmap using set_text from matplotlib and keep dollar sign

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, annotations, seaborn

I would like to add a comma separator to the annotation produced by the following code, keeping the dollar sign and using the `set_text()` and `get_text()` functions. I see that t returns a "text object" but I am not sure how to modify the object to return the desired result.

How can I add a comma separator while keeping the dollar sign and using the `for t in ax.texts` loop?

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
import seaborn as sns
#
datas = []
#
for item in list("ABC"):
    for year in [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]:
        x = randint(1000, 2000)
        datas.append([item, year, x])

df = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns = ["Item", "Year", "Value"])
df = df.pivot("Item", "Year", "Value")
ax = sns.heatmap(df, linewidths = 0.5, xticklabels = True, yticklabels = True, cmap = "OrRd", annot = True, fmt = "d")

for t in ax.texts:
    t.set_text("$" + t.get_text())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python string format actually has this builtin:

```
'${:,d}'.format(1000)
```

gives `'$1,000'`

So you can try

```
t.set_text('${:,d}'.format(int(t.get_text())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `fmt=',.0f'`

i.e.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df, linewidths = 0.5, xticklabels = True, yticklabels = True, cmap = "OrRd", annot = True, fmt=',.0f')
```